# How can Using Left property in Right to Left sheets?

Tags: vba, excel

It seems I should using `Left` property to set horizontal position of my chart as bellow.

```
Sheets("sheet1").ChartObjects("InsuranceChart").Left = 'h position
```

My sheets are Right to Left.
But
Note that above property calculated from left side of sheets.

I need whole sheet width or alternative property for using in Right to Left sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Cells.Width - _
(Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("InsuranceChart").Width + _
Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("pvtReport").TableRange1.Left)
```

This is suitable for Right to Left WorkSheets direction.

Line1: Overal WorkSheets width.
Line2: Charts width
Line3: Table from Rigth!
Note that `TableRange1.Left` property in Right to Left WorkSheets is distance of Right side of Table to Left side of whole WorkSheet, and `ChartObject().Left`, for ever is distance of Left side of the Chart from Left Side of the WorkSheet.